# How can I perform a group by inside my case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, row-number

In the query below, I am trying to find the top 2 employer names and employee counts in my database for each city.

It is currently working, but I want it to now sum all of the employers with the same EmpName and return that for each of the "Jobs" columns.

So I need the rank fixed so that it finds the largest employers grouped by name, and then I need that value to be returned in the select statement.  How can this be achieved?

The Statement:

```
SELECT
    x.City,
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.rk = 1 THEN x.EmpName END) AS Top1_Employer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.rk = 1 THEN x.Employees END) AS Top1_Jobs,
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.rk = 2 THEN x.EmpName END) AS Top2_Employer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.rk = 2 THEN x.Employees END) AS Top2_Jobs

FROM(SELECT emp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp.City ORDER BY 
emp.Employees desc) AS rk FROM Employer emp) x

GROUP BY x.City
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Input:

EmpName   Employees    City
Emp1      100          Los Angeles
Emp2      150          Phoenix
Emp3      50           Los Angeles
Emp1      20           Los Angeles
Emp1      100          Los Angeles
Emp2      150          Phoenix
Emp3      50           Los Angeles
Emp1      20           Los Angeles

Ouput:

City         Top1_Employer   Top1_Jobs   Top2_Employer   Top2_Jobs
Los Angeles  Emp1            240         Emp2            150
Phoenix      Emp2            300         NULL            NULL
.....
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, your question doesn't mention city which is at the heart of the provided query.

Comment: Almost there...please show desired output as your textual explanation is not quite clear. And why pivot then if you need to aggregate by Employer names?

Comment: I added an output example in the sample data section.

Comment: Nope, the current output isn't summing the jobs.

Comment: Why not use another window function `sum(employees) over (partition by empName) as SumEmpEmployees`

Comment: @xQbert Because I need the rank to use the summed amount too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do aggregation on city and empname to find the total employees and rank based on that in each city. and then pivot the results.

Try this:

```
select City,
    MAX(case when rk = 1 then EmpName end) as Top1_Employer,
    MAX(case when rk = 1 then Employees end) as Top1_Jobs,
    MAX(case when rk = 2 then EmpName end) as Top2_Employer,
    MAX(case when rk = 2 then Employees end) as Top2_Jobs,
    MAX(case when rk = 3 then EmpName end) as Top3_Employer,
    MAX(case when rk = 3 then Employees end) as Top3_Jobs,
    MAX(case when rk = 4 then EmpName end) as Top4_Employer,
    MAX(case when rk = 4 then Employees end) as Top4_Jobs,
    MAX(case when rk = 5 then EmpName end) as Top5_Employer,
    MAX(case when rk = 5 then Employees end) as Top5_Jobs
from (
    select city,
        empname,
        sum(Employees) as Employees,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (
            partition by emp.City order by sum(Employees) desc
            ) as rk
    from Employer emp
    group by City,
        empname
    ) x
group by City
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/OHH24082)

Comment: The issue with this answer is that I still need access to the individual rows for other sections of the query.  The x.* has been removed.

Comment: @Jack - It was never there in your own query. Beside this answer the question you asked. If you have a different question, ask a new one.

Comment: You are right.  And I figured it out for my use case.  Thanks for the help Gurwinder.